# Stack trace with destructor call

Tags: c++, access-violation, crash-dumps

I am finding it hard to debug an access violation issue in my code.
Trying to understand the stack traces and dump files i wanted to understand this.
If an access violation is happening in a destructor of a class,
say for example

```
abc::~abc()
{
  int *p = NULL;
  *p = 100;
}
```

Will the stack trace collected in the dump file contain this destructor call ?

Please help me understand this.

Comment: Yes, the stack trace (if you are lucky enough to have it) will have destructor in it.

Comment: No, that's rare.  Destructors are usually easy to inline, you'd be lucky if it is virtual.  Doesn't help you that much anyway, the vast majority of destructor crashes are caused by memory corruption that happened much earlier.

Comment: Is this actual code?  Destructor would need ()

Comment: If using [GCC](http://gcc.gnu.org/) compile with `g++ -g3 -fno-inline -Wall -Wextra` then use the `gdb` debugger

Comment: @CarlH Edited the code snippet. Thanks for mentioning it

Comment: @BasileStarynkevitch I am compiling it in windows environment

Comment: It is known that GCC is also available on Windows. Indeed I would suggest you to develop on Linux (where the tools and libraries are free software whose code you can study, and where you have [valgrind](http://valgrind.org/)....)

Comment: @HansPassant Thanks for your comment. Yes, i doubt there is an access violation happening in one of the destructor and i am not able to follow up the stack. Are there any specific tool or something to find this.